# Rule for sending email when order exceeds a defined weight

Tags: commerce, rules

I set up some shipping tariffs (with module [shipping weight tariff](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping_weight_tariff)). But now i want to define a rule that sends an email to the shopowner in case the order total weight is over a certain weight. How should this rule be defined? The one i made is not working, it is not kicking in (for sake of simplicity in the below example I chose to show a message instead of sending an email):

```
    { "rules_shipping_weight_alert" : {
    "LABEL" : "Shipping Weight Alert",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "WEIGHT" : "-8",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "commerce_physical", "commerce_shipping" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_shipping_collect_rates" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_is_of_type" : { "entity" : [ "commerce-order" ], "type" : "commerce_order" } },
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "commerce-order" ], "field" : "field_physical_weight" } },
      { "commerce_physical_rules_order_weight_comparison" : {
          "commerce_order" : [ "commerce-order" ],
          "operator" : "\u003E",
          "value" : "9",
          "unit" : "kg"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Shipping weight alert!" } } ]
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just to be sure, but you now used _Show a message on the site_ for debugging right? Because this Rule is not configured to send a mail at all.

Comment: Yes, i  am aware of this – it is just for demonstration purposes! also i gave the rule a weight of -7 so it is executed early. I updated my question text to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling I've found the solution myself:

```
    { "rules_notice_overweight" : {
    "LABEL" : "Overweight",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "commerce_physical", "rules", "commerce_shipping" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_shipping_calculate_rate" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "commerce_physical_rules_order_weight_comparison" : {
          "commerce_order" : [ "commerce-line-item:order" ],
          "operator" : "\u003E",
          "value" : "10",
          "unit" : "kg"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Total weight is over 10kg" } } ]
  }
}
```

The problem in my first code example was the trigger "commerce_shipping_collect_rates". It has to be "commerce_shipping_calculate_rate" instead. I hope someone can benefit from that.